# ionic 2 not showing screensaver or icon

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, splash-screen

I have followed the instructions [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html) to show screen saver and create an icon for the app in Android. I am using a png image that I created in MsPaint of the required minimum size: 2252 x 2252 px. I don't think using the psd to create an image in photoshop is mandatory otherwise they would have said so in that link. Inspite of following the documentation, I still get the default splash screen and icon

Here is my platform

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9 
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47 
ios-deploy version: Not installed 
ios-sim version: Not installed 
OS: Windows 10 
Node Version: v6.9.2 
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Here is my config.xml. This contains some new preferences that I have added after researching online, since others have found those tweaks to have worked for them. Unfortunately it hasn't worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.helloworld" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>HelloWorld</name>
  <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1"/>
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

Please help as I am not able to find anything online to fix this issue.

Comment: use this command for icon generating: ionic resources --icon

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is cordova cli v6.4.0 which I then downgraded to v6.3.1 fix the issue.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Do what i did and downgrade. That worked for me.